# Rayleigh Quotient with $2n \times 2n$ Matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, data-analysis, block-matrices

I need help understanding a problem.

For a bonus question in our problem set, we are told that $\bf{A}$ is a $2n \times 2n$ symmetric matrix of form $$\bf{A} = \begin{pmatrix} A_1 & A_3 \\ A_3 & A_2 \end{pmatrix}$$ where each entry is a $n \times n$ matrix, and that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are symmetric. We are then asked to prove that $$\lambda_\min (\bf{A}) \leq \min(\lambda_\min (A_1),\lambda_\min (A_2)).$$ We are asked to do this using the Rayleigh quotient $\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$, which we've learned is bounded below and above by the smallest and largest eigenvalues of the matrix respectively, but is $x$ in this case supposed to be a vector of the form $\begin{pmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \end{pmatrix}$. If so, wouldn't this multiplication return a $n \times n$ matrix instead of a real value which can be bounded above and below by $\lambda$? It's all confusing me a bit, and I would appreciate it if someone could even just give me some definitions to work with, or some clarification on how the Rayleigh quotient could apply or work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R(A,x)$ denotes the Rayleigh quotient. Then
$$
\lambda_{\min}(A)=\min_x R(A,x) \le \min_{x:x_{n+1}=\ldots=x_{2n}=0} R(A,x)=\lambda_{\min}(A_1).
$$
Similarly,
$$
\lambda_{\min}(A)=\min_x R(A,x) \le \min_{x:x_{1}=\ldots=x_{n}=0} R(A,x)=\lambda_{\min}(A_2).
$$

---

Here

$$
A=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
a_{1,1} & \cdots & a_{1,n} & a_{1,n+1} & \cdots & a_{1,2n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n,1} & \cdots & a_{n,n} & a_{n,n+1} & \cdots & a_{n,2n} \\ \hline
a_{n+1,1} & \cdots & a_{n+1,n} & a_{n+1,n+1} & \cdots & a_{n+1,2n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{2n,1} & \cdots & a_{2n,n} & a_{2n,n+1} & \cdots & a_{2n,2n} \\
\end{array}\right]
\quad\text{and}\quad x=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_{1} \\
\vdots  \\
x_{n}\\ \hline
x_{n+1} \\
\vdots  \\
x_{2n} \\
\end{array}\right].
$$

Comment: Could you help explain what the Rayleigh quotient even is when it comes to these block matrices?

Comment: There is no difference! It is $x^{\top}Ax/x^{\top}x$ regardless of how $A$ is split into blocks.

Comment: What are the dimensions of $x$ though? Are the entries of $x$ real?

Comment: $x$ should be compatible with $A$. $\text{dim}(x)=2n$ in your case. $x$ is a real vector when $A$ is real.

Comment: I see I see. I think I had a misconception that the entries of the matrix were matrices itself, and not "numbers" in that sense. Now I realize the entries are just simply real values and the block matrix notation is just a notational thing and not a different mathematical structure.